# Stack Overflow Careers profile is not showing up on Stack Overflow settings

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, jobs

I can't set my Stack Overflow Careers profile on my Stack Overflow settings. It's still asking me to create a Careers profile. I think this is a bug in Stack Overflow, but if not, what can I do?

Comment: No i tried it several times, it's not working..

Comment: Marking this as status-completed as I can see you have your Careers profile on your SO profile now.

Comment: I'm having this same issue.